# how to hide a checkbox value in cshtml file - mvc html

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a code

```
@if (Model.Subscribed)
{ 
<div>
@Html.CheckBox("Subscribed", false) I would like to unsubscribe! 
</div>
}
else
{ 
<input type="hidden" name=Subscribed" value="true" />
}
```

I want to hide the whole sentence after checkbox is checked. It is hidden the first time when submit is hit but once when  back to form page the checkbox sentence is back with unmarked checkbox.

Can any one help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can someone please answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for?

```
@Html.CheckBox("Subscribed", false, new { onclick = "javascript:$('#spnSubscribed').hide();" }) <span id="spnSubscribed">I would like to subscribe!</span>
```